# IL2CPP Threadpool worker(54): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

Tags: c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine, plugins

My plugin:

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    
@interface SampleClass:NSObject
    + (BOOL)isInstalledX: (NSString*) app;
    + (void)sendX: (NSString*) target;
@end
      
@implementation SampleClass      
    + (BOOL)isInstalledX: (NSString*) app {
        return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString: app]];
    }
    + (void)sendX: (NSString*) target{
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:target]]) 
        { 
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:target]];
        }
    }
@end

NSString* convertString(const char* string)
{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: string];
}

extern "C"
{      


    bool isInstalled(const char* text){
        return [SampleClass isInstalledX: convertString(text)];
    }

    void send(const char* url){
        [SampleClass sendX: convertString(url)];
    }
}
```

Every time i'm trying to build it returns [IL2CPP Threadpool worker(54): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPY2u.png) on line return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: string];.

But when I remove **send** function the converion in **isInstalled** function is working.

Also C# code:

```cs
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool isInstalled(string text);
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void send(string text);

...

if (!isInstalled("fb-messenger://"))
    btn.gameObject.SetActive(false);

...

send("fb-messenger://share?link=" + content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of function `send` to `sendToApplication` and it's worked...